# ASP.NET MVC5 EF Databse first - Call SP when saving a record

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using VSPro 2013 and SQL Server 2008 R2 and working with database first.

I'm new to MVC. I'm developing a fairly simple and short-lived line of business app. Originally, it was just fairly simple CRUD, so worked great. Now I have to call a stored procedures to insert some new data (there is biz logic in SP and they are maintained by DB folks).

I plan to learn how to use repo and UOW correctly, but I have to get this done quite quickly.

Right now my app is just using the scaffolded views, models and controllers and I've modified a bunch of views to show related data, etc. How can I change the submit action to call a stored procedure instead of the usual POST action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,VersionRef,IntJobNo,ImportedFileList,TotalCopies,FormatFileID")] Job job)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Jobs.Add(job);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.FormatFileID = new SelectList(db.FormatFiles, "ID", "Name", job.FormatFileID);
            ViewBag.INTJobNo = new SelectList(db.IntJobNos, "JobNo", "JobNo", job.IntJobNo);
            return View(job);
        }
```

TIA

Mark

Comment: if it's database first, then just add the procedure to your model and call it after `db.savechanges();`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896231(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JamieD77. Thanks. doesn't db.savechanges save the record I'm editing? I need to replace the default save with my SP call, but not sure where that would go in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Double click on your .edmx file to open it
- Right click on the window that opens and choose "Update Model from Database...".
- Under the Add
  tab choose the stored procedure you need
- Click finish

This will add it as a function in the C# code.

Once you have added it, call it with code similar to below:

```
var myTableEntities = new MyTableEntities();
var myResult = myTableEntities.StoredProcedureName([Params]);
```

See: [Calling Stored Procedures from Entity Framework](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx)

-KB

Comment: Thanks KB. I see the stored procedure, but not sure WHERE I call it from

Comment: @mark1234, Added code to answer your comment "I see the stored procedure, but not sure WHERE I call it from"